# JsonObject put issue with method

Tags: java, android, json, class

Very new so bear with me. 
The method `BloodPressure()` is called in `MainActivity` and the values are fetched and "put" into the `jsonObject`.

Method `getBloodPressure()` will return this jsonobject and is called in another module.
The jsonobject in `getBloodPressure()` is always empty {}. 
I have try to debug. So I can see the json is created exactly. But when I "return jsonObject" in getBloodPressure it just resets and becomes {}.

How do I call the jsonObject with bloodPressure values?

MainActivity

```
private static void dumpDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
.
.
.
healthdata.BloodPressure(type, systolic, diastolic, sdate, edate );
//printed this and it works perfectly fine

}
```

HealthData.java

```
public class HealthData {

    private String steps,heartRate,systolic, diastolic, bloodGlucose,bodyTemperature,age, startDate, endDate, dataType;
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    public HealthData(){
        super();
    }

    public void BloodPressure(String type, String sys, String dia, String sdate, String edate) {
        dataType = type;
        systolic = sys;
        diastolic = dia;
        startDate = sdate;
        endDate = edate;
        try {
            jsonObject.put("dataType", dataType);
            jsonObject.put("SystolicValue", systolic);
            jsonObject.put("DiastolicValue", diastolic);
            jsonObject.put("startDate", startDate);
            jsonObject.put("endDate", endDate);
            Log.v("json:", String.valueOf(this.jsonObject));     //prints json successfully
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(e.toString(), null);
        }
    }

    public JSONObject getBloodPressure() throws JSONException {
        return jsonObject;            //trying to return json but its empty
    }

}
```

AnotherModule:

```
public void getHealthData(Callback cb) {
    try {
        HealthData healthData = new HealthData();
        JSONObject json = healthData.getBloodPressure();   ///calling it here
        cb.invoke(null, json);
    } catch (Exception e){
        cb.invoke(e.toString(), null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your code and found you didn't call `BloodPressure()` method before `getBloodPressure()`.
I think that you should call `BloodPressure()` method before `getBloodPressure()`

So your another module code like this.

```
public void getHealthData(Callback cb) {
    try{
        HealthData healthData = new HealthData();
        healthData.BloodPressure("type", "sys", "dia", "sdate", "edate") // you must call this method.
        JSONObject json = healthData.getBloodPressure();   ///calling it here
        cb.invoke(null, json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        cb.invoke(e.toString(), null);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I think you should not create new instance of `HealthData` in `getHealthData()` method.

```
public void getHealthData(Callback cb) {
    try{
        //HealthData healthData = new HealthData(); // this line is wrong. So I removed this line.
        JSONObject json = healthData.getBloodPressure();   ///calling it here
        cb.invoke(null, json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        cb.invoke(e.toString(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my updated question. I call BloodPressure() in MainActivity. I get all the data and "put" into a jsonObject. but when I call getBloodPressure() it returns empty {}

Comment: Please look your Another module. you create new instance of healthData, so it's empty now. you shouldn't new HealthData() in getHealthData() method.